# Select all preceding children of the same parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a few `<span>` elements inside of a `<div>`. When you hover over one `<span>` it should highlight all the **preceding**`<spans>` and the hovered `<span>`.

How can I do this using just CSS or jQuery?

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6zm3E/)**

I suspect a jQuery answer will do the following, but I can't find functions for 1 & 2.

1. Get the child # of the currently hovered element
2. Select all the children up to that number
3. Add the 'hover' class to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery :

```
$('span').hover(​​​​​function(){
    $(this).prevAll().addClass('hover'); 
},function(){
    $(this).prevAll().removeClass('hover'); 
});​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/R6uBq/)

This uses [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to select all the preceding spans of the same div. No need to use the index of the current element but you could have got it with the index function and then you would have used the lt selector (`$(this).sibblings(":lt("+$(this).index+")")`). Of course prevAll is much simpler.

As noticed by elclarns, this can be shortened in

```
$('span').hover(function(){
    $(this).prevAll().toggleClass('hover'); 
});​
```

Comment: god i love jQuery. Thanks dystroy!

Comment: thats a good answer I wrote one up for closest .container , then nextUntill - this is alot simpler

Answer (score 1):

This is, depending on compatibility, possible with CSS, albeit there's no added class-names:

```
div:hover span {
    /* colours all descendent spans of hovered-div */
    background-color: #ffa;
}

div:hover span:hover,
div:hover span:hover ~ span {
    /* 'de-colours' the hovered-span, and
         the subsequent sibling spans */
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you fix it so that it doesn't colorize the last div if you hover it ?

Comment: It should be noted that [this isn't compatible with IE7 or IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Comment: @dystroy: I'm not entirely sure I understand your first comment, but I assume you mean the flickering when the `:hover` leaves a `span`, highlighting all the `span`s, until another `span` is hovered? If so, no (though it might be possible in some way). As for IE < 9, no: it's a quite limited demonstration, unfortunately. But still, as you say, 'interesting.' If only as a proof-of-concept... =)

Comment: +1 because even if it's hard to use it today we will all have to get accustomed to those selectors for the day we can pronounce the death of IE8.

Answer (score 0):

as per the example provided, I can't see anything difficult here, we will use the prevAll() function to select all the previous siblings based on the current item.

```
    $("span").hover(function(){
       $(this).prevAll().addClass("hover");

},    function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
})​
```

a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6zm3E/1/